# DEFINE_SHAPE Global Mapper Clip/Crop Raster on Import

Tags: global-mapper

I have a tool that builds global mapper workspaces (GMW) reads text file of inputs and matching crop files. 
Right now it's broken because the coordinates it's putting in are in the wrong format. (we're reprojecting the coordinates from Lambert Conformal Conic NAD83 to Geographic WGS84 with the tool)

What are these  XY coordinate pairs format in?
DEFINE_SHAPE SHAPE_NAME="CUSTOM_CROP_POLY"
    **86719.728,-17769.678**
    86724.447,-41056.077
    86722.043,-67997.092
    86701.989,-72329.834
    73283.127,-72367.604
    -69940.830,-72419.735
    -69979.327,-24217.469
    -70028.004,72186.140
    -70025.776,72891.778
    71991.936,72903.615
    86649.571,72883.481
    86696.503,68216.201
    86711.350,53742.419
    86719.728,-17769.678
END_DEFINE_SHAPE

It's not Geographic WGS84 these are in that and they don't work
DEFINE_SHAPE SHAPE_NAME="CUSTOM_CROP_POLY" 
    -80.096204,35.076877
    -80.098833,34.866366
    -80.100575,34.729513
    -80.101942,34.622879
    -80.102655,34.583728
    -80.249271,34.584553
    -80.499368,34.586011
    -81.814207,34.584342
    -81.819085,35.020018
    -81.828698,35.891928
    -81.828741,35.898313
    -81.820307,35.898379
    -80.499383,35.899769
    -80.249394,35.898266
    -80.086403,35.896796
    -80.086432,35.854564
    -80.087970,35.723620
    -80.096204,35.076877
END_DEFINE_SHAPE
http://www.bluemarblegeo.com/knowledgebase/global-mapper-19/cmd/DEFINE_SHAPE.htm?tocpath=Scripting%20Reference%7CDefine%20data%7C_____1

Answer (score 1):

Those XY coordinates pairs are in the native coordinate system of the file you want to apply the cropping to.
Your Geographic WGS84 coordinate pairs will work only for files which are originally stored in the Geographic WGS84 coordinate system.